# Xcode 7 beta 3 crashes creating core data ns managed subclass or entity

Tags: core-data, swift2, xcode7

Having a problem with Xcode 7 crashing when I try to create a core data entity. I can create the entity and add attributes but after that it crashes... when Xcode resumes the entity is no longer there. The error seems to reflect something in Core Foundation, but it is not specific, just an exception.

I've already asked this in the Apple Dev Forums with no response.

Sometimes I can actually get past the stage where I create the NS Managed Subclass files, but as soon as the files appear to be generated I get the same error, a crash, and upon resume the entity and the subclass files are no longer there.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try Xcode 7 beta 4 or [report it](https://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple.

Comment: I wasn't aware beta 4 was available, I looked at the SDK page yesterday and didn't see that. I have reported it to Apple. I will go look for beta 4 now, thank you robertvojta.

Comment: Released few minutes, maybe hours, ago :-)

Comment: Downloading now, thanks again.